# Java ProtectionDomain seems not to work

Tags: java, security, permissions, sql-grant

I have some problem with granting permissions in Java. I would like to implement app (e.g. `myapp`), which runs normaly, with all permissions, but when it loads code (from .jar or .class)(e.g. `foo.jar` and `bar.class`) from specific location (e.g `http://example.net/libs`), this code should run with specific permissions.

I thought the only one which I have to do is grant all permissions to `myapp` (via policy file) and then just simply create `ProtectionDomain` (on location `http://example.net/libs/*` and with specified permissions) and run libs via `AccessController`.

<strike>But when I grant permissions (**only**)(via policy file, see bottom) to `myapp`, they are granted to all code (including libraries `foo.jar` and `bar.class`) - which musn't.</strike>

<strike>So I stopped exploring how to grant permissions to libs and I have to solve this problem first.</strike>

*(see EDIT at bottom)*

#### Structure

I have `myapp` which contains main class (`myapp.Main`) and it's located in `/home/java/`:

```
/home/java/src/myapp/Main.java
/home/java/bin/myapp/Main.class
```

and libraries

```
http://example.net/libs/foo.jar
http://example.net/libs/bar.class
```

#### Implementation

I wrote `myapp.Main.java` like this:

```
package myapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //myapp should access
        System.out.println("myapp.Main: " + System.getProperty("user.home"));

        //find Foo class
        Class<?> fooClass = findFooClass();

        //invoke some its method
        // this should fail
        try {
            System.out.println(fooClass.newInstance().toString());
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

    }

    private static Class<?> findFooClass() throws IOException {
        URL fooClassURL;
        try {
            fooClassURL = new URL("http://example.net/libs/foo.jar");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{fooClassURL});
        Class<?> fooClass;
        try {
            fooClass = ucl.loadClass("foopackage.Foo");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            ucl.close();
        }

        return fooClass;
    }

}
```

and class `foopackage.Foo` like

```
package foopackage;

public class Foo {

    public Foo() {
    }

    private void tryProperty() {
        System.out.println("foopackage.Foo: " + System.getProperty("user.home"));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        tryProperty();
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

#### Running

When I run myapp via this command

```
 java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/home/java/myapp.policy myapp.Main
```

where file `myapp.policy` looks like

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/java/*" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

<strike>it outputs twice home directory and then original value of `Foo.toString`.</strike>
*(see EDIT at bottom)*

I am asking - what am I doing wrong? What did I disunderstand?

---

#### EDIT:

The reason why permissions were granted to whole code was simply - while I was exploring security, I've got litle bit tangled and I granted all permissions via file `~/java.policy`.

So, now I can grant permissions via policy file as expected. But still not works granting permissions via `AccessController`. `myapp.Main` has permissions granted via policy file and works fine (so it prints once home directory), but when it (via `AccessController.doPrivileged`) calls `FooClassToStringAction`'s action, the `foopackage.Foo` has no permission to access property (which I IMHO grant by `ProtectionDomain`). Updated `myapp.Main` class' code:

```
package myapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.security.AccessControlContext;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.AllPermission;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class Main {

    public static class FooClassToStringAction implements PrivilegedAction<Void> {

        private Class<?> fooClass;

        public FooClassToStringAction(Class<?> fooClass) {
            this.fooClass = fooClass;
        }

        @Override
        public Void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(fooClass.newInstance().toString());
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //myapp should access
        System.out.println("myapp.Main: " + System.getProperty("user.home"));

        //find Foo class
        Class<?> fooClass = findFooClass();

        ProtectionDomain domain = createProtectionDomain();
        PrivilegedAction<Void> action = new FooClassToStringAction(fooClass);
        AccessControlContext context = new AccessControlContext(new ProtectionDomain[] {domain});
        AccessController.doPrivileged(action, context);

    }

    private static Class<?> findFooClass() throws IOException {
        URL fooClassURL;
        try {
            fooClassURL = new URL("http://example.net/libs/*");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        URLClassLoader ucl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {fooClassURL});//new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{fooClassURL});
        Class<?> fooClass;
        try {
            fooClass = ucl.loadClass("foopackage.Foo");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            ucl.close();
        }

        return fooClass;
    }

    private static ProtectionDomain createProtectionDomain() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://example.net/libs/*");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        //I tried url=null or url=file:/- but no change
        CodeSource codesource = new CodeSource(url, (Certificate[]) null);

        PermissionCollection permissions = new Permissions();
        //add various permissions to libraries here
        permissions.add(new AllPermission());

        return new ProtectionDomain(codesource, permissions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not picking up the `foopackage.Foo` from the system class loader? (You can check from the `Class`' `ProtectionDomain`.) (Also `URLClassLoader.newInstance` includes a couple of checks that `new URLClassLoader` misses out.)

Comment: No, `foopackage.Foo` isn't on the classpath. And using `newInstance` did not helped too.